# The solid blue and red lines formed in the plot split into two

Tags: gnuplot

The following code used to work to produce free energy diagrams. An issue has arisen where the solid red and blue lines formed don't form a single line, but split into two.

I am really not sure how to fix this issue as this script worked previously just fine. I unfortunately cannot show the plot itself here so feel free to run this and see what you get. Could it be an OS problem, perhaps? My macOS is Ventura 13.2 and using Gnuplot 6.0

```
  ###subblocks to free energy diagrams###

  set terminal emf font "Sans Bold,25" enhanced
  set terminal emf size 620,530
  makebold(text) = sprintf("{/:Bold %s}", text)
  set border 15 front lt black linewidth 3.000 dashtype solid
  set xlabel "Reaction Coordinate"
  set xrange [-0.2:5.2]
  set xtics nomirror scale 0
  set ylabel "Free Energy (eV)"
  set ylabel offset character 4.5,-3.0,0 font "Sans Bold,25" enhanced
  set xlabel offset character 0,0.6,0 font "Sans Bold,25" enhanced
  set yrange[-5:0.4]
  set ytics in nomirror font "Sans Bold,25" enhanced
  set key noautotitle samplen 2
  set key enhanced
  set errorbars 0
  dx = 0.2
     myFileOut(s) = sprintf("%s.emf",s)
     myTitle(s) = sprintf("%s",s)
    
inputFiles = '/Users/total.dat'
outputDirs = "/Users//Free-Energy-2/"

  do for [i=0:2] {
    stats inputFiles index i every ::::0 u (s=strcol(4),0) nooutput
    set output outputDirs.myFileOut(s)
    set title myTitle(s) offset 0,-0.93, 0

    plot inputFiles  index i u 0:2:(dx):xtic(makebold(strcol(1))) w xerr lc "blue" lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(2), \
    ''  index i u 0:3:(dx)         w xerr lc "red"  lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(3), \
    x1=y1=NaN ''  index i u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "blue" nohead, \
    x1=y1=NaN ''  index i u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$3,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "red" nohead
}
       set output   # close the last file
### end of script
```

The data used:

```
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.40 V" "FeZn (7, 9)"
O_{2}                   0.00   -2.29
O@^*_{2}               -0.03   -2.31
OOH^*                  -1.05   -3.51
O^*                    -1.54   -4.18
OH^*                   -4.30   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92


"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.30 V" "FeZn (1, 9)"
O_{2}                   0.00   -2.29
O@^*_{2}               -0.03   -2.21
OOH^*                  -1.05   -3.51
O^*                    -1.54   -4.18
OH^*                   -4.30   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92
```

Comment: Please tell us the OS you are using and the version of gnuplot.  I can see one problem to start with - inputFiles is a string containing the name of a file. But your stats command puts it in quotes so the program tries to open a file named "inputFiles" instead of trying to open a file named "total.dat". If I correct that and change the font size to 15 rather than 25 I get output that looks reasonable. I don't think it is possible to attach an emf file so I attach the output from png instead.  The emf output looks the same except for line thickness.  Does this match what you get?

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

I can't attach a figure to a comment, so here's the same thing as an answer even though I haven't actually answered anything yet.

Please tell us the OS you are using and the version of gnuplot.

I can see one problem to start with - inputFiles is a string containing the name of a file. But your stats command puts it in quotes so the program tries to open a file named "inputFiles" instead of trying to open a file named "total.dat". If I correct that and change the font size to 15 rather than 25 I get output that looks reasonable.

I don't think it is possible to attach an emf file so I attach output from the png terminal instead. This is using gnuplot 5.4.10 on linux. The emf output I get looks the same except for line thickness. Does this match what you get?

[image]

**Gnuplot version 6 answer**

Ah, version 6.  Now it becomes clear.  The issue is that your solid lines are not created by plot style `with lines` or `with vectors`.  They are created by plotting `with xerrorbars`.   In version 6 the errorlines and errorbars plot styles leave a gap in the error bar at the actual data point so that an asymmetric error range can be shown:  ┣━━━━━━━ • ━━┫
A solid line with no gap would make it difficult to see the position of the data point.

As in the `with linespoints` plotting style, the size of this gap is controlled by `set pointinterval box <width>`.  From the documentation for `help pointintervalbox`:

> The command `set pointintervalbox` controls the radius of  this
> blanked-out region.  It is a multiplier for the default radius, which
> is  equal to the point size. `unset pointintervalbox` draws no
> blanked-out region.

It is an oversight in the documentation that this explanation is only mentioned with regard to `with linespoints`.  It also applies to all plot styles with error bars, and the documentation should be amended to say this.  It should also be amended to mention this as a change from version 5.

So the answer is to add the command `set pointintervalbox 0.0` or `unset pointintervalbox`. Either command will reduce the width of the gap to zero.

I had initially thought all the lines in your plot were created using `with vectors`, but that was just me overlooking the fact that you were mixing multiple plot styles in the one command.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:macos]

Comment: @Ethan this is what I should get, however the solid red and blue lines have a gap kind of like this - - instead of being one solid line. The version of gnuplot I am using is 6.0 and my mac OS is Ventura version 13.2

Comment: @ethan thank you for this. I figured it was the xerr that was responsible for this. Will implement this change and get back to you. Thank you